# How to get selected radio button value to pass to UpdateView in Django?

Tags: radio-button, django-class-based-views, django-2.0

I want to get selected value by radio button and  pass it to the update view but I couldn't find a way. Both views are class based.

Exception Value:
Reverse for 'update-author' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:

ListView :

```
class Dashboard(ListView):
model = Author
template_name='catalog/dashboard.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(EditDashboard, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["authors"] =Author.objects.all()
    context["publishers"] =Publisher.objects.all()
    context["genres"] =Genre.objects.all()
    return context
```

UpdateView:

```
class UpdateAuthor(UpdateView):
model = Author
fields = '__all__'
template_name='catalog/updateauthor.html'
context_object_name = 'author'
```

Model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank =True)
date_of_death = models.DateField(null=True, blank =True)


class Meta:
    ordering = ['first_name', 'last_name']

def __str__(self):
    return  f' {self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

Form in template :

```
<form action="{% url 'update-author' ????? %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for author in authors %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="{{ author.id }}" value="{{ author.id }}">
        <label for="author">{{ author.first_name}} {{ author.last_name}}</label><br>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you have a listView with all the authors publishers and genres, and you want to call the updateView with the author selected.

One way is to use javascript:

- give an id to the form tag :
- map an event on click to the submit button
- get the selected radiobox element and value
- change the form action value with the value you get
- call the submit event

Here is some sample of Jquery you can use to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myformid').submit(function(event) {
        //prevent the form submition on click
        event.preventDefault();
        //get the selected value
        var selected_author_id =$('input[name="choice"]:checked').val();
        console.log(selected_author_id);
        //add this value to our form action attribute
        $(this).attr('action', 'update-author/'+String(selected_author_id));
        //finaly submit the form
        $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
    });
});
```

Don't forget to import jquery as well

Comment: Hi Ben, can you give an example to do it using Javascript.